I encountered an error when running the git push -u origin main command in the command line. The error message is:
I have just completed my React JS project and I wanted to host it on GitHub, but once I created the repo without adding a README file, in the command line while writing the git push -u origin main command, this error pops up
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs

I am not able to get the error, I have tried multiple times by creating a new error, but still the problem persists.
I am expecting that the file will be completely pushed to the repo, with all the code bases that I have built.

You have to follow the following steps if you want your code to get pushed into your repo : 
1>git branch check your branch first(where you currently are)
2>git add .
3>git commit -m "Initial Commit"
then execute

git push -u origin branch_name
